# Why can we add together the x and y components of chain rule derivatives of multivariable functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Suppose that $x = g(t)$ and $y = h(t)$ are differentiable functions of $t$ and $z = f(x,y)$

Then, $z$ is a differentiable function of $t$ and $\mathrm dz/\mathrm dt = (\partial z/\partial x)(\mathrm dx/\mathrm dt) + (\partial z/\partial y)(\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt)$

The above is from a calc lecture, and I ask: why can we add the $x$ and $y$ components? And likewise if $x$ and $y$ (and thus $z$, a function of $x$ and $y$) depended on multiple variables--why can we add them?

Comment: For information about how to present mathematical formulas on this site, start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation ... for the $\partial$ symbol, use `\partial`.

Answer (score -3):

My preference is to define partials in the following way: if $z = f(x, y)$, then $dz = \partial_x z + \partial_y z$.  In other words, $dz$ is the result of adding together the changes in $z$ which result from allowing $x$ to vary and the changes in $z$ which result from allowing $y$ to vary.

A better notation, in my opinion, for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ is actually $\frac{\partial_x z}{dx}$. So, you can derive this as follows:

$$ dz = \partial_x z + \partial_y z $$

Divide both sides by $dt$:

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x z}{dt} + \frac{\partial_y z}{dt}$$

Now, $\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dy} = 1$, so we can freely multiply by this if we want.  So, we can say:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x z}{dt}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial_y z}{dt}\frac{dy}{dy}$$

Now, using basic fraction rules, we can rearrange this as:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x z}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial_y z}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} $$

Rewriting this in "typical" partial derivative notation gives:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} $$

Comment: This is not a proof, and treating derivatives as fractions obscures rather than clarifies, particularly in the context of partial derivatives. Also, your alternative notation is easily confused with the more standard Euler notation, which writes $\partial_x f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: And frankly, I am not even sure what $\partial_x f$ even *means* in your notation.

Comment: It was defined at the beginning - $\partial_x f$ is the amount of the total differential $df$ that comes from $x$ being allowed to change.